# SQL- The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

[image]

While executing the following query, I am getting the Multi Part Identifier could not be bound error. Kindly help.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    C.CustomerID, C.LastName, A.ArtistID, A.LastName 
FROM 
    CUSTOMER as C, ARTIST as A 
WHERE 
    CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.CustomerID = CUSTOMER.CustomerID 
    AND CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.ArtistID = ARTIST.ArtistID;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.LastName, A.ArtistID, A.LastName 
FROM CUSTOMER as C, ARTIST as A WHERE CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.CustomerID=C.CustomerID AND CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.A=ARTIST.ArtistID
```

Comment: Still getting the same error for CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.CustomerID and CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.A.

Comment: I got the answer.

Comment: SELECT C.CustomerID, C.LastName, A.ArtistID, A.LastName FROM CUSTOMER as C, ARTIST as A, CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT as J
WHERE J.CustomerID=C.CustomerID AND J.ArtistID=A.ArtistID ;

Comment: use inner join >>>>   select C.customerID, c.Lastname, A.ArtistID, A.lastname
 from customer c
 
 inner join CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT CA
 on CA.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
 and CA.artistid=C.artistID

Comment: @AlanMathew What you are doing here is an *old-fashioned-join* and should better be done with `JOIN` clauses...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.CustomerID without using it in select query..

use this:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.LastName, A.ArtistID, A.LastName 
FROM CUSTOMER as C, ARTIST as A,CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT as CAI WHERE CAI.CustomerID=C.CustomerID AND CIA.ArtistID=A.ArtistID;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.LastName, A.ArtistID, A.LastName 
FROM CUSTOMER C
inner join ARTIST  A 
on a.CustomerID=c.CustomerID 
AND a.ArtistID=c.ArtistID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use commas to build relation between tables. Use proper [JOINs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx).
In your script you haven't included the table `CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT` in the `FROM` clause and without mentioning the table you can't access the columns ( `CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.CustomerID and CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT.ArtistID`) .

Change your script like below ,move the conditions from `WHERE` clause to `ON` using appropriate `JOINS` and also try to use aliases for representing the table.

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, C.LastName, A.ArtistID, A.LastName 
FROM  CUSTOMER  C
       JOIN CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT CA ON C.CustomerID=CA.CustomerID
       JOIN ARTIST  A ON CA.ArtistID=A.ArtistID
```